# creating an attachment for Google App Engine

Tags: email, google-app-engine, attachment

Now my webapp is nearly finished I would like to email the result to myself in the form of an attachment. The content of the attachment is the content of the variable "Gcode" this is one big string that looks like:
"G00X12.46Y18.51
G01X12.46Y21.62
G01X13.79Y21.62
G00X10.00Y23.00"
When trying to send the mail I get an error that says: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. I found the attachment has to be a bytestring. Is this the problem?

```
class send_mail(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    material = self.request.get('material')
    thickness = self.request.get('thickness')
    fileName = self.request.get('fileName')
    Gcode = self.request.get('Gcode')
    sheetSize = self.request.get('sheetSize')
    recieve_address = 'me@hotmail.com'
    attachments=[(fileName+'.nc', 'Gcode')]
    if not mail.is_email_valid(user_address):
      Gcode = ''
    else:
      confirmation_url = Gcode
      sender_address = "theLaserLab.com <theLaserLab@gmail.com>"
      subject = "Order content"
      body = "The attached file: %s.nc. Is supposed to cut from a sheet of %s that is    %smm thick and has a %s dimension." % (fileName, material, thickness, sheetSize)
      mail.send_mail(sender_address, recieve_address, subject, body, attachments)
```

Comment: Have you tried the bytes() method? It'll make a bytestring.